# How can i compare values within a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, iteration

I am developing a Bio-metric election system but i am facing problem regarding election results.

I got this array after executing a query.

```
Array
(
    [paty1] => Array
        (
            [NA122] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [count] => 2
                )    

            [NA2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [count] => 0
                )

                [NA56] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [count] => 1
                )

        )

    [party2] => Array
        (
            [NA122] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [count] => 0
                )

            [NA2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [count] => 0
                )

            [NA56] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [count] => 0
                )

        )

)
```

This array is stored in `$data` and it can have unlimited indexes.

Now if count of `[Paty1][NA122]` is greater then count of `[Party2][NA122]` so i will declare `Party1` win in `NA122` and i have to compare it with n number of indexes.

e.g. there is another index pary3 so firstly I will compare count of [`party1][NA122]` with `[party2][NA122]` and then with `[party3][NA122]` and winner will be the one with greater count . Can you please help me??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach(current($Result) as $Const=>$val){

 echo "Winner of Constituency '$Const': ". findWinner($Const,$Result).PHP_EOL;

}

function findWinner($Const, $Result){
 $Max = 0;
 $Winner = '';

  foreach($Result as $Party => $ConstList){
     if($ConstList[$Const]->count>$Max){
        $Max = $ConstList[$Const]->count;
        $Winner = $Party;
     }
  }
 return $Winner;
}
```

Check live code here:
https://www.tehplayground.com/x5sPu7JxuexOdwU8

Comment: Hey can you please suggest what it should do if two parties have same count for a particular constituency?

Comment: Refer to this: https://www.tehplayground.com/Uumj1xFwWvH3Vz17   -  You will need to return an array and if the array have more than one element (coun(array)>1) then there are multiple winners.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to get the party with the max count for a given NA#.
You can use a function like this:

```
function maxParty($data, $na) {
    $max = null;
    foreach($data as $party => $values) {
        if(is_null($max)) {
            $max = $party;
            continue;
        } else {
            if($values[$na]->count > $data[$max][$na]->count) {
                $max = $party;
            }
        }
    }
    return $max;
}
```

Then you feed this function with a $data array and the NA# you want to calculate the max party with. For example

```
$winner = maxParty($data, 'NA122');
```

It will return the key for the winner party. I.e. "party1"

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this:

```
<?php
    $data=getData();
    $maxValue;
    $maxKey;

    foreach($data as $key => $paty)
            if(!isset($maxValue) || $paty->count>$maxValue){ 
                    $maxValue=$paty->count;
                    $maxKey=$key;
            }
    echo "$maxValue $maxKey";

    function getData(){
            $a=array();
            for($i=1;$i<100;$i++)
                    $a["paty$i"]=(object) array("count"=>$i);
            return $a;
    }
?>
```

Explanation:
getData returns an array like the one you described

foreach($data as $key => $paty) - iterates through the entire array

if ( ) -- checks if the current value is greater than the previous max

If you want to know more about PHP:
[foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php), [objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php), [arrays](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp) and [google](https://google.com)